# IntelliJ hangs when selecting a JDK

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I have installed IntelliJ 10.5.1 CE and are about to create my first Java project in it. But I have to select a path to JDK. And when I press the button "Configure..." and the file dialog comes up - then IntelliJ hangs, and I have to kill it. I use it on Mac OS X.

How can I solve this?

[image: intellij]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following bugs:

- [IDEA-70046](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-70046) IntelliJ 10.5 freezes on filebrowser usage (german) Mac OS X 10.5 & 10.6
- [IDEA-71695](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-71695) Open file dialog hangs on Mac

It may help if you disable native file chooser dialogs:

> Command+Option+Shift+/ | Registry | uncheck
>   "ide.mac.filechooser.native"

If it doesn't help, [attach a thread dump](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-260) to the second issue.

Comment: Thanks, it seem to be the second bug. Is there any other way I can select a JDK in IntelliJ?

Comment: Nothing happens when I press Ctrl+Option+Shift+/ in IntelliJ.

Comment: It's the same as Search | Find Action, type Registry in the search field to open hidden settings. You need some project to be open for this menu to activate.

Comment: The only key that starts with "ide.mac." is `ide.mac.filechooser.showhidden.files`

Comment: Try to edit Info.plist and add `-Dnative.mac.file.chooser.enabled=false` in VMOptions: http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-197.

Comment: I'm still having this problem, with IntelliJ running on JDK 1.8.0_20. Unchecking `ide.mac.filechooser.native` resolved the issue but this should probably be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a PC under windows. In Device Manager, I disabled the CD-ROM drive. It's basically hanging on a local or network drive that is mounted.